# How to define a function and a query in the same with block?

Tags: oracle

I can create a subquery in a with block.

```
WITH b AS (SELECT 2 FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM b;
```

I can create a function in a with block

```
WITH 
FUNCTION a (a IN INTEGER)
    RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN a + 1;
END;
SELECT a (COLUMN_VALUE) FROM sys.ODCINumberList (1);
```

But I haven't succeeded to define a function and a query in the same with block.

```
WITH 
 b AS (SELECT 2 FROM DUAL);
FUNCTION a (a IN INTEGER)
    RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN a + 1;
END;
SELECT a(COLUMN_VALUE) FROM sys.ODCINum
```

> [Error] Execution (13: 8): ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier

(A is the name of function)

I have to use "," instead of ";" and other things likewise but to no avail

I know that I can define a function directly in a pl/sql package, but the function I want to create will be used only in one query. Thefore it's not worth doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [`WITH` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6), the PL/SQL declarations need to come before the sub-query factoring clauses.

> [image: WITH clause syntax diagram]

Therefore the function declaration needs to come first.

Also, a query can only return a single result set; therefore you need to combine the output using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION a (a IN INTEGER)
    RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN a + 1;
END;
b (value) AS (
 SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value FROM b
UNION ALL
SELECT a(COLUMN_VALUE) FROM sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(2);
```

Which outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1c86e55e16af4491304c9166e7373bbe)*