# How to define a pipelined table function within a with statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

It's possible to defined a function within a with statement ([How to define a function and a query in the same with block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688501/how-to-define-a-function-and-a-query-in-the-same-with-block)). But I fail to define a pipelined function inside a with statement.

```
WITH
    FUNCTION f (a IN INTEGER)
        RETURN SYS.odcinumberlist
        PIPELINED
    IS
        ret   INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        FOR z IN 1 .. a
        LOOP
            PIPE ROW (z);
        END LOOP;

        RETURN;
    END;
SELECT * FROM f(3);  --I tried with table(f(3)) too
```

> [Error] Execution (2: 1): ORA-06553: PLS-653: aggregate/table functions are not allowed in PL/SQL scope

Is it possible to define a pipelined table function within a with statement and how?

If it is possible, I would like to do that with a table of record. Therefore I need to know how defined type within a with statement too.

Answer (score 1):

Within a subquery-factoring clause, you can make a non-pipelined function that returns a collection:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION f (a IN INTEGER)
  RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
IS
  v_list SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST();
BEGIN
  FOR z IN 1 .. a LOOP
    v_list.EXTEND;
    v_list(v_list.COUNT) := z;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN v_list;
END f;
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(f(3));
```

Which outputs:

> | COLUMN_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |
> | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a2e3f0bff30cf084e5c53184808a2fdf)*

---

> If it is possible, I would like to do that with a table of record.

A record is a PL/SQL data type; you cannot use it in an SQL statement. Instead use an `OBJECT` data type and declare it in the global SQL scope before you run your query (no, you cannot declare it locally inside your query).

> Therefore I need to know how defined type within a with statement too.

Again, you cannot as the SQL syntax does not allow it. See the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71739014/1509264).

You can declare it globally:

```sql
CREATE TYPE test_obj IS OBJECT (
  w1 INTEGER
);

CREATE TYPE test_obj_table IS TABLE OF test_obj;

WITH FUNCTION f (a IN INTEGER)
  RETURN test_obj_table
IS
  v_list test_obj_table := test_obj_table();
BEGIN
  FOR z IN 1 .. a LOOP
    v_list.EXTEND;
    v_list(v_list.COUNT) := test_obj(z);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN v_list;
END f;
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(f(3));
```

Outputs:

> | W1 |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |
> | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=efd001b275b152bbaabd0109e1d9305c)*